# Is there a better way to solve this 'Rosseta Stone' programming challenge in javascript?

Tags: javascript, coding-efficiency

*Hello, I recently came acrosss this programming challenge and managed to find a workable solution. The challenge contains various type of data input and my code seems to have workable solution that fullfils the data need however the code seems more hardcoded than generic. I am wondering if there is any way I can get rid of the if..else condition in the following code and combine a solution for numeric and non numeric data input. There is a for loop in each part and seems a bit redundant. Does anyone know how the code can be written more efficiently? There is a HINT in the program however I am not sure I have used it correctly.*

Rosetta Stone
Programming challenge description:
The Rosetta stone is an ancient decree written into stone that was used by archeologists to translate between Greek and Ancient Egyptian languages.

Write a program to decode messages using a Rosetta for translation. The "Rosetta" will be a series of character sets paired with english words or characters. If you translate the encrypted message correctly, you will find the hidden message.

HINT: Spaces that are not part of a fragment must be preserved

Input:
Multiple lines of input will be given. The first line of input will be the message to translate to English.

All other lines of input will be the Rosetta needed to translate. The fragments of each pair will be separated by a pipe character, one pair per line of input.

For example:

```
Hola Mundo
Mundo|World
Lunes|Monday
Hola|Hello
```

Translates:
Hola Mundo

into:
Hello World

Output:
The translated text, which will be a real English phrase

Test 1
Test Input

```
Hola Mundo
Mundo|World
Lunes|Monday
Hola|Hello
```

Expected Output : Hello World

Test 2
Test Input

```
mieux vaut prévenir que guérir
merci|thank you
que|than
malade|sick
mieux|better
guérir|to heal
chien|dog
vaut prévenir|to prevent
beurre|butter
s'il vous plaît|please
```

Expected Output: better to prevent than to heal

Test 3
Test Input

```
5748494348 574159 544845 57494E44 424C4F5753
41|A
42|B
43|C
44|D
45|E
46|F
47|G
48|H
49|I
4A|J
4B|K
4C|L
4D|M
4E|N
4F|O
50|P
51|Q
52|R
53|S
54|T
55|U
56|V
57|W
58|X
59|Y
5A|Z
```

Expected Output : WHICH WAY THE WIND BLOWS

**Code**

Run this as JS file & comment/uncomment arrays to use different input data.

```
function Solve() {
  /* var arr3 = [ 'Hola', 'Mundo' ]
    var arr4= [ 'Mundo', 'World', 'Lunes', 'Monday', 'Hola', 'Hello' ] */

  /*  var arr3 = [ 'mieux', 'vaut', 'prévenir', 'que', 'guérir' ]
     var arr4 = [ 'merci','thank you','que','than','malade','sick','mieux','better','guérir',
    'to heal','chien','dog','vaut prévenir','to prevent','beurre','butter', 's\'il vous plaît','please' ] */

  var arr3 = [ '5748494348', '574159', '544845', '57494E44', '424C4F5753' ]
  var arr4 = [ '41','A','42','B','43','C','44','D','45','E','46','F','47','G','48','H','49','I',
  '4A','J','4B','K','4C','L','4D','M','4E','N','4F','O','50','P','51','Q','52','R','53','S','54',
  'T','55','U','56','V','57','W','58','X','59','Y','5A','Z' ]

    var newarr = [];
    var hasNumber = /\d/;

    for (var i = 0; i < arr3.length; i++) {            

        if (hasNumber.test(arr3[i])== true){
            var char = '';
            for (k=0; k< arr3[i].toString().length; k++){

                for (var j=0; j<arr4.length; j++) {
                    //value = arr4[j].toString();
                   // var spl =  value.split(" ");
                    if(arr3[i].toString().substr(k,2) === arr4[j]){
                        char = char + arr4[j+1] ;                       
                    }
                } k= k+1;
            }  newarr.push(char.toString()); 

        } else {

            for (var j=0; j<arr4.length; j++) {
                value = arr4[j].toString();
                var spl =  value.split(" ");
                //console.log(spl);
                if (spl[0] === arr3[i]) {
                    newarr.push(arr4[j+1]) ;            
                }     
            }    

    }        



} console.log(newarr.toString().replace(/,/g, ' ')); 

}

console.log(Solve());
```

Comment: You might want to ask this question at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Sure. Will try CodeReview. Thanks.